# How to connect push button in dock widget form?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

Following this [tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/building_a_python_plugin.html) as a guide, I created a plugin using the Plugin Builder with the dock widget form. I am now trying to connect a `pushButton` to a function. The following is a snippet of code:

```
def __init__(self, iface):
    self.dockwidget.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.test_print)

def test_print(self):
    print 'It works!'
```

However, I receive an:

> error when calling its classFactory() method

I have also tried:

```
def initGui(self):
    QObject.connect(self.dockwidget.pushButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.test_print)
```

But then there's an error calling its `initGui()` method. Any pointers?

---

**Edit**:

I have tried the following variations in the `run(self)` function, I no longer receive errors but nothing is printed in the console:

```
def run(self):
    #self.dockwidget.connect(self.dockwidget.pushButton,SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.test_print)
    #self.dockwidget.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.test_print)
    QObject.connect(self.dockwidget.ui.pushButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.test_print)
```

Comment: Did you try to put the connect in the run(self) method ?

Comment: @Azimo - Thanks, just tested it. I no longer receive the errors but nothing is printed in the console.

Comment: QgsMessageLog.logMessage('It works!','test')   ??

Comment: @Azimo - Not showing up when clicking the `pushButton` unfortunately. Works fine if I stick it in the `run(self)` function, which just loads the message log so atleast something happens!

Comment: But, can you confirm that the "objectName" property of the QPushButton (in your .ui file) is "pushButton".

Comment: @Azimo - Yes, I can confirm it is "pushButton".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os

from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignal

FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'my_dockwidget_base.ui'))


class myDockWidget(QtGui.QDockWidget, FORM_CLASS):

    closingPlugin = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Constructor."""
        super(myDockWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        # After setupUI you can access any designer object by doing
        # self.<objectname>, and you can use autoconnect slots - see
        # http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html
        # #widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect
        self.setupUi(self)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.closingPlugin.emit()
        event.accept()
```

---

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import * #QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication, Qt
from PyQt4.QtGui import * #QAction, QIcon
from qgis.core import *
# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
import resources

# Import the code for the DockWidget
from my_dockwidget import myDockWidget
import os.path

class myPlugin:

    # cutting other methods (__init__, initGui, unload..etc..)
    def run(self):
       if not self.pluginIsActive:
           self.pluginIsActive = True

           # openOtherWin is outside of run method...
           self.dockwidget.but_openOtherWin.clicked.connect(self.openOtherWin)
```

---

Comment: Thanks for posting, I will try testing this at some point!

Comment: Ok... Adding now the .py of plugin class ...

Comment: I created a test plugin and used your method and it worked. Interesting, I will accept your answer but will also keep mine in case it could work for others ;)

Answer (score 3):

Guess the answer was simpler than I thought. Had to insert everything into the `run(self)` function. So the following code works:

```
def run(self):

    def test_print():
        print 'It works!'

    self.dockwidget.pushButton.clicked.connect(test_print)
```

Comment: Not for me, strange....  :/

Comment: @Azimo - Haha indeed, were you also using dockwidgets or a dialog form?

Comment: dock... I copy .py in an answer and will delete after...

Comment: @Azimo - Keep the answer in please. If it works for you then it could work for others in a similar situation ;)